# Access network of PC2 from virtualbox installed on PC1

Tags: networking, virtualbox, routing, bridge, tunneling

I am going to attend one seminar where I need to bring laptop with installed Virtualbox and Windows 7 running inside it. My laptop is too old to handle Virtualbox with Windows 7 and native Linux system together. So I was assuming to install Virtualbox on my (far newer) desktop PC and use some routing magic so Virtualbox will be accessible as it was connected to network where my laptop physically is. Is this possible? In general my question is: Is possible to install Virtualbox on PC1 and with some magic ensure that Virtualbox installed on PC1 will be able to access PC2 physical network? I guess something might be possible via some TUN/TAP, iptables, ssh etc. hacking but I do not know how exactly.

OS: Debian 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

1. Use OpenVPN in tap mode. Bridge the tap interface with the LAN interface on both systems. This should work with broadcast packets (NetBIOS), too.
2. Add another IP address to the LAN interface. The Windows VM will be known to the other hosts by this address. The configure DNAT for this address and forward the packets to your desktop PC. This probably does not work well with broadcast packets.

Comment: can you please point me to some tutorials?

Comment: @WakanTanka Unfortunately I am not aware of any. I have not even used TAP yet (I always use OpenVPN with TUN interfaces).

Comment: And what about second option? Also I am a little bit confused with first option. Who should be client and who server laptop or desktop or no matter who?

Comment: @WakanTanka You just need a tunnel between the two systems. It doesn't matter which one is the server; that affects only the creation of the tunnel but not its operation when it's up and running. But it probably makes more sense to make the desktop PC the server as you know its IP address in advance which is probably not the case with your seminar IP.